How many types of transport does SignalR use?
In the article from 2020 we have:

WebSocket
Server Sent Events
Forever Frame (for Internet Explorer only)
Ajax long polling

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr
In the article from 2023 we have:

WebSocket
Server Sent Events
Long polling

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/introduction?view=aspnetcore-8.0
Does it mean now we have 3 transports and Forever Frame was removed? Chatgpt still tells about 4 transports.....

I think the reason is because internet explorer (IE) died on June 15, 2022!!!

This is related with the browser, the FF is just for the IE(IE is deprecated ) and now the asp.net core SingalR clients javascripts library doesn't support the old browser IE and it just support three transport.
From the doc:
The JavaScript client doesn't support Internet Explorer and other older browsers. The client might have unexpected behavior and errors on unsupported browsers.
